# How can I match a phrase in In Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to match any phrase between two specific characters. For example:Let these be characters the phrases are between:**x x** . I would like to find, for example, any  of this: **x**Hi there**x** or **x**How are you**x**.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression in the search mode and give the appropriate expression. Here the expression .* will match all the text between "you" and "created". I hope this helps[image: Trick is to use regular expression]